# Dependency injection - Call to undefined method - Laravel 4

Tags: php, dependency-injection, laravel-4, ioc-container

I have a Facade Player where i set up a function info, this function will give me the information of the players, the my issue is when i call that function by dependency injection it throw me the error:

*Call to undefined method Team\Player\Facades\Player::info()*

instead if i call that function doing `Player::info();` it Work! Why with the depency throw me that error?

following my class Player

```
class Player {

use Team\Player\Models\User;
use Team\Player\Models\Team;
use Team\Player\Models\Fighter;

  public function info($user_id)
  {
    return Fighter::with('team','user')->where('player_id','=',$user_id)->first();
  }

}
```

My controller where i try to call the dependecy

```
class MatchController extends BaseController {

    protected $match;
    protected $player;

    function __construct(Match $match,Player $player) { // dependency injection
        $this->match = $match;
        $this->player = $player;
    }

    public function getInfoPlayer() 
    {
        $player_id = Input::get('user_id');
        $player = $this->player->info($player_id);
        return View::make('site/team/event/scripts/infoPlayer')->withPlayer($player);
    }


}
```

and my service provider where i bind my class

```
public function register()
    {

         $this->app['player'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
      {
        return new Player;
      });

         $this->app->booting(function()
        {
          $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
          $loader->alias('Player', 'Team\Player\Facades\Player');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not showing ALL namespaces and uses clauses from your files, where the conflict is.

But I can do a little guess from what you gave us:

If you receive

```
 Call to undefined method Team\Player\Facades\Player::info()
```

When you do

```
$player = $this->player->info($player_id);
```

Is because

```
function __construct(Match $match, Player $player) { // dependency injection
}
```

Is telling, somehow, Laravel to instantiate

```
Team\Player\Facades\Player
```

Instead of using the already instantiated:

```
Team\Player\Player
```

Which is

```
$this->app['player'];
```

So, one possibility is having a

```
uses Team\Player\Facades\Player;
```

In your `MatchController` class. Where you should have

```
use Player;
```

or

```
use Team\Player\Player;
```

But this will make Laravel to inject a new instance of `Team\Player\Player` and not `$this->app['player']`, to do that, you would have to

```
function __construct(Match $match, PlayerInterface $player) {}
```

And then

```
App::bind('PlayerInterface', function($app) {
    return $app['player'];
});
```

Well... something like that.

**EDIT**

You'll have to create that inteface, because PHP will complaint about not finding it.

The best place to put this binding is in its own ´app/bindings.php´ file, but you'll have to load it in your `app/start/global.php`:

```
require app_path().'/filters.php';
require app_path().'/bindings.php';
```

Your controller should look like this:

```
uses Team\Player\PlayerInterface;

class MatchController extends BaseController {

    ...

    function __construct(Match $match, PlayerInterface $player) 
    {
       ...
    }

    public function getInfoPlayer() 
    {
       ...
    }

}
```

You Player class must implement that interface:

```
class Player implements PlayerInterface {

    ...

}
```

Comment: I can just say thank you very much!!!! This is a good explanation but i have to ask something about. You bind PlayerInterface, but i haven't that Inteface i should create one? wich is the best place for bind the player interface? it's fine on the serviceProvider file?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to create an (empty) interface, because PHP will complaint about not finding that class or interface. Just edited to answer your questions properly.

Comment: Ok, Thank you! But i created that interface and bind it how you did on the answer adding the right namespace but it come with an error, Class PlayerInterface does not exist, Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php","line":522. Sorry but i'm trying to understand better. Cheers!

Comment: Looks like you're now just missing a uses, edited again.

Comment: Thanks!! we are close thank you for the patience but now it come with this error: Argument 2 passed to MatchController::__construct() must implement interface Team\\Player\\PlayerInterface, instance of Team\\Player\\Player

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot to add that too. It's exactly what the error is saying, your Player class must implement that Interface. Edited.

Comment: Hello antonio, i'm very sorry to disturb you again but i have another small issue with the IoC. I'll very glad if you can find 3 minutes for help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311716/interface-laravel-doesnt-bind-why